# Getting emoji object to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, discord.py, emoji

Right now im my journey of discordbot making, I'm tackling reaction roles! I think I have most everything setup, but I can't seem to find a way to get from an emoji object to an emoji unicode, so I can compare them and add the reaction. Here's what I have so far:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print(payload)
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji
    print(emoji.id)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def reactionrole(ctx, title:str, description:str, name:str, value:str):
    title = ''.join(title)
    description = ''.join(description)
    name = ''.join(name)
    value = ''.join(value)
    embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.teal(), title = title, description = description)
    embed.add_field(name = name, value = value, inline=False)
    message = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    with open("reactionroles.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    addon = {"guild-id" : ctx.guild.id}, {"message-id" : message.id}, {"roles" : []}, {"emojis" : []}
    data[ctx.guild.id] = addon
    with open("reactionroles.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def reactionadd(ctx, emoji, *role:str):
    role = ''.join(role)
    with open("reactionroles.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    message_id = data[str(ctx.guild.id)][1]['message-id']
    message_id = int(message_id)
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)
    data[str(ctx.guild.id)][3]['emojis'].append(emoji)
    print(role)
    data[str(ctx.guild.id)][2]['roles'].append(str(role))
    with open("reactionroles.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

So the command `reactionrole` creates the embed, and writes some placeholder data into a json file. Afterwards, the `reactionadd` command adds the emoji unicode to a json array, and the role to a different json array. When on a reaction add, in `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)`, payload only has the name of the emoji, and not the unicode. Because of this, I', not able to compare the two to see what role goes to what emoji. I can't save the origional, in `reactionadd` because I would run into problems in `on_reaction_add`. I'm lost on getting the unicode from the payload this is my final reach out. Here's what's inside payload:

```
<RawReactionActionEvent message_id=759903170721087508 user_id=146348630926819328 channel_id=754904403710050375 guild_id=665787149513261057 emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='�' id=Non
 event_type='REACTION_ADD' member=<Member id=146348630926819328 name='Chai' discriminator='6396' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=665787149513261057 name="ChaiBot's Playground" shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=34>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

From an [Emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Emoji) object you can get the unicode character from `emoji.name`, or if you are looking for the unicode name you can use the python [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) library:

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.name(emoji.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have realized my error! I was able to compare the unicode from `reactionadd` to `payload.emoji` the entire time! I was not able to see originally though, that vs code shows the unicode as an emoji (in terminal), and not as the string. That makes much more sense now! Thanks to all they helped!